# Cocoapod dependencies no longer being bundled in app

Tags: cocoapods

I have a set of projects like the one with the Podfile below that all share two common development pods.

```
platform :ios, '11.2'
use_frameworks!

workspace "AppWorkspace"

target 'App' do
    project "App/app"
    pod 'PromiseKit', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'LibKit', :path => '../LibKit'
    pod 'LibUI', :path => '../LibUI'

    target "AppBeta" do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

The file system is laid out like:

- AppProject

  - App
- LibKit
- LibUI

For brevity here's the Podspec for the LibUI since it also contains the resource bundles:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'LibUI'
  s.module_name      = 'LibUI'
  s.version          = '0.1.1'
  s.summary          = 'A collection of UI components.'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
             A collection of shared UI components
  DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/Foo/LibUI'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'ME' => '------@---------.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/Foo/LibUI.git' }

  s.platform = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
  s.swift_version = "4.0"

  s.source_files = 'LibUI/Classes/**/*'
  s.resource_bundles = {
     'LibUIBundle' => ['LibUI/Assets/*.xib', 'LibUI/Assets/*.xcassets']
  }
  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
end
```

When building and running the app, I run into this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/PromiseKit.framework/PromiseKit
Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/486B5EFB-6F18-45A7-AA78-07D18C0909FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/830433F4-AA5A-402E-9A81-E2A7C6A61EA7/AppBeta.app/AppBeta
Reason: image not found
```

This error repeats for each of the pods until I change the `Mach-O Type` build setting in the Pods project from `Dynamic Library` to `Static Library` for each of them.

However, then I'm met with the following set of errors:

```
Unknown class _TtC8LibUI18SVTabBarController in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class _TtC8LibUI22SVNavigationController in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class _TtC8LibUI22SVNavigationController in Interface Builder file.
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/486B5EFB-6F18-45A7-AA78-07D18C0909FC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/72B43E50-7A5D-4122-8CD3-09B862C5C6D4/AppBeta.app> (loaded)' with name 'MessageView''
```

The missing classes referenced from the storyboard file are in the LibUI pod, and the Module field is properly set to `LibUI` for the respective instances of those classes in Interface Builder.

The `MessageView` class is a member of the LibUI Pod. A class func of that class attempts to load a XIB from the `resource_bundles`, LibUIBundle, as follows:

```
let libUIBundle = Bundle(for: MessageView.self)
let resourceBundleURL = libUIBundle.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("LibUIBundle.bundle")
let resourceBundle = Bundle(url: resourceBundleURL!)
guard let messageView: MessageView = UINib(nibName: "MessageView", bundle: resourceBundle).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? MessageView else { return }
```

This was updated recently to reflect suggestions in other SO posts I searched for.

All of this previously worked until updating to iOS 11, which we put off until recently. It seems as though the Pods project is not properly copying frameworks (when dynamically linked) and resources into my App's bundle.

I've already updated Cocoapods. I also deleted my Workspace and project files for this project, and then recreated them with the defaults---re-adding all the files back to the project---to avoid any lingering build settings that might have been affecting this situation. Am I doing something foolish? How has no one else run into this if it's a bug?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.4.0.rc.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.13.2 (17C88)
       Xcode : 9.2 (9C40b)
         Git : git version 2.14.3 (Apple Git-98)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ e205fb520bcc24de216064c32914c85a2aaa25cc
               LibPods - https://github.com/Foo/LibPods.git @ 2c7954bf3d48a9d21ff9967fe6aa31d371e063e7
```

#### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the relevant issues on Github that I'll link here in case anyone else comes across this:

[Pods that are used by embedded dynamic frameworks can't be found in linked targets.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6284)
[No 'Embed Pods frameworks' build phase when building custom framework ?](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6123)